# Firebase Storage Downloads Doesn't Resume on Network Reconnection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

**The Story**

I am using Firebase Storage to upload and download files. The **upload** works almost perfectly and if the device looses internet connection for a few minutes, then the upload stops, but it automatically resumes once the connection is back.

**The Problem**

I was expecting this exact same behaviour for the **downloads** as well. But it doesn't work like that. If my device looses internet connection, the downloads fails abruptly and doesn't automatically once the connection is back after a few seconds.

Is this the normal behaviour or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

This is the error,

> com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.

```
Read error: ssl=0xb7e7a510: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
                                                                           javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0xb7e7a510: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
                                                                               at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:699)
                                                                               at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:113)
                                                                               at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:48)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:446)
                                                                               at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
                                                                               at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: plz ref this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499262/firebase-storage-handling-network-interruptions-when-download-in-progress?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But my download instantly fails if the connection is lost. It doesn't retry at all. What should be the problem?

Comment: @DaminiMehra I have edited the question with the exact exception thrown immediately when the internet connection is lost. Can you please help?

Comment: Plz send this issue to firebase team. they people are help for this. or chk this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously

Answer (score 0):

You can manage robust downloads using the Android Download manager with the download url (reference.getDownloadUrl()).

See:
[Android download manager completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477493/android-download-manager-completed)

We'll improve this handling in an upcoming release.
Also I recommend using the many image download SDKs (like Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide)