# Catch error on failed file upload with firebase storage

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to prepare for the inevitability of when a user uploads to firebase storage but doesn't have an internet connection. Currently, if i use the following and turn of all internet connections it never reaches the `catchError` it just waits and prints the dowloadUrl when the connection comes back.

```
  FirebaseStorage.instance.setMaxOperationRetryTimeMillis(10);
  final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("AllUsers").child(uuid).child(fileName);
  final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image, const StorageMetadata(contentLanguage: "en"));
  Uri downloadUrl;
  await uploadTask.future.then( (UploadTaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    downloadUrl = snapshot.downloadUrl;
    print(downloadUrl)
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
```

Does this mean I don't have to worry about caching each image for upload later and that it's being handled? I'm assuming not but that would be great.

Update:

Adding this instead of the then catch:

```
  try {
    downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
    print("$downloadUrl");
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
```

didnt make the call after the request.

Update 2:

Tried adding the following:

```
  FirebaseStorage.instance.setMaxUploadRetryTimeMillis(10);
  FirebaseStorage.instance.setMaxOperationRetryTimeMillis(10);
  FirebaseStorage.instance.setMaxDownloadRetryTimeMillis(10);
```

which returns `E/StorageException(13068): The operation retry limit has been exceeded.` but through the console and not caught as an error in my `catchError` or `try catch` block.

Comment: If you use `await` rather use `try`/`catch` instead of `catchError`. It's easy to use `catchError` in a way that doesn't catch what you thought it would.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i tried what you said but no luck, see my update

Comment: "didn't make the call" means `print(error)` wasn't called? I guess it just waits and retries until the network becomes available (thus no error), but if your app is killed, then nothing will happen.

Comment: yes, sorry `print error` didnt get called and when i turned wifi on the `try` didnt happen either, is there a way around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499262/firebase-storage-handling-network-interruptions-when-download-in-progress has some information. That should mostly apply to Flutter as well.

Comment: I'd create a bug report. I also run into such an issue where a `PlatformException` was logged to the console but couldn't be caught in Dart.

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

(This doesn't respond the exact question)

What I would do in your situation is I would save the file to disk first, and then delete it once Firebase picks it up. The flow becomes

`user -> save local -> firebase -> delete local`.

Instead of

```
user -> firebase -> (on success) -> done
                 -> (on failure) -> save local -> firebase
```